# Optimizing Multilingual User Data Query

Tags: sql, mysql, laravel, database, query-optimization

I hope you are doing well.

I have the following query to get the users with their translated names and country information which needs speed optimization:

```sql
SELECT users.*,
       COALESCE(ANY_VALUE(trans.first_name), ANY_VALUE(fb_trans.first_name)) AS first_name,
       COALESCE(ANY_VALUE(trans.second_name), ANY_VALUE(fb_trans.second_name)) AS second_name,
       COALESCE(ANY_VALUE(trans.third_name), ANY_VALUE(fb_trans.third_name)) AS third_name,
       COALESCE(ANY_VALUE(trans.last_name), ANY_VALUE(fb_trans.last_name)) AS last_name,
       CONCAT(COALESCE(ANY_VALUE(trans.first_name), ANY_VALUE(fb_trans.first_name)), ' ', COALESCE(ANY_VALUE(trans.second_name), ANY_VALUE(fb_trans.second_name)), ' ', COALESCE(ANY_VALUE(trans.third_name), ANY_VALUE(fb_trans.third_name)), ' ', COALESCE(ANY_VALUE(trans.last_name), ANY_VALUE(fb_trans.last_name))) AS full_name,
       countries.flag AS country_flag,
       countries.code AS country_code
FROM `users`
INNER JOIN `user_translations` AS `fb_trans` ON `fb_trans`.`user_id` = `users`.`id`
INNER JOIN `languages` AS `fb_lng` ON `fb_lng`.`id` = `fb_trans`.`language_id`
INNER JOIN `languages` AS `lng` ON `lng`.`lang_code` = 'ar'
LEFT JOIN `user_translations` AS `trans` ON `trans`.`user_id` = `users`.`id`
AND `trans`.`language_id` = `lng`.`id`
INNER JOIN `countries` ON `countries`.`id` = `users`.`country_id`
WHERE `users`.`deleted_at` IS NULL
GROUP BY `users`.`id`;
```

A user (a row in users table) must be inserted using a transaction along with a translation (in user_translations table) which will be the first translation and the default/fallback (`fb_trans` and `fb_lng` joins)

Let's say a user has registered on our app when the app language was set to "en" (languages.id = 1). That user will be added to `users` table and `user_translations` table with language_id = 1 (en). That user's default translation is English.

Then the language changed on the app from "en" to "ar" (languages.id = 2) (Arabic), the query will try to get the Arabic translation of the user if existing, otherwise, it will get the user's first/default/fallback translation which is the English one.

#### Explain Query

Explain query before adding an index for `deleted_at` column in `users` table (The query triggers `log_queries_not_using_indexes`):

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SIMPLE | lng | NULL | ref | languages_lang_code_index | languages_lang_code_index | 767 | const | 1 | 100.00 | Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort |
| 1 | SIMPLE | users | NULL | ALL | PRIMARY,users_uuid_unique,users_country_id_foreign,users_city_id_foreign,users_district_id_foreign | NULL | NULL | NULL | 16669 | 10.00 | Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop) |
| 1 | SIMPLE | countries | NULL | eq_ref | PRIMARY | PRIMARY | 4 | db_name.users.country_id | 1 | 100.00 | NULL |
| 1 | SIMPLE | fb_trans | NULL | ref | user_translations_user_id_index,user_translations_language_id_index | user_translations_user_id_index | 8 | db_name.users.id | 1 | 100.00 | NULL |
| 1 | SIMPLE | fb_lng | NULL | eq_ref | PRIMARY | PRIMARY | 8 | db_name.fb_trans.language_id | 1 | 100.00 | Using index |
| 1 | SIMPLE | trans | NULL | ref | user_translations_user_id_index,user_translations_language_id_index | user_translations_user_id_index | 8 | db_name.users.id | 1 | 100.00 | Using where |

```php
# Test 1: Query_time: 0.277862  Lock_time: 0.008804 Rows_sent: 16313  Rows_examined: 114731
# Test 2: Query_time: 0.218047  Lock_time: 0.000165 Rows_sent: 16313  Rows_examined: 114731
# Test 3: Query_time: 0.220287  Lock_time: 0.000153 Rows_sent: 16313  Rows_examined: 114731
```

Explain query after adding an index for `deleted_at` column in `users` table (Now the query does not trigger `log_queries_not_using_indexes` which is nice):

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SIMPLE | lng | NULL | ref | languages_lang_code_index | languages_lang_code_index | 767 | const | 1 | 100.00 | Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort |
| 1 | SIMPLE | users | NULL | ref | PRIMARY,users_uuid_unique,users_country_id_foreign,users_city_id_foreign,users_district_id_foreign,tmp_idx_deleted_at | tmp_idx_deleted_at | 5 | const | 8334 | 100.00 | Using index condition; Using where |
| 1 | SIMPLE | countries | NULL | eq_ref | PRIMARY | PRIMARY | 4 | db_name.users.country_id | 1 | 100.00 | NULL |
| 1 | SIMPLE | fb_trans | NULL | ref | user_translations_user_id_index,user_translations_language_id_index | user_translations_user_id_index | 8 | db_name.users.id | 1 | 100.00 | NULL |
| 1 | SIMPLE | fb_lng | NULL | eq_ref | PRIMARY | PRIMARY | 8 | db_name.fb_trans.language_id | 1 | 100.00 | Using index |
| 1 | SIMPLE | trans | NULL | ref | user_translations_user_id_index,user_translations_language_id_index | user_translations_user_id_index | 8 | db_name.users.id | 1 | 100.00 | Using where |

```php
# Test 1: Query_time: 0.248500  Lock_time: 0.006678 Rows_sent: 16313  Rows_examined: 114458
# Test 2: Query_time: 0.268973  Lock_time: 0.000258 Rows_sent: 16313  Rows_examined: 114458
# Test 3: Query_time: 0.242067  Lock_time: 0.000304 Rows_sent: 16313  Rows_examined: 114458
```

##### Notes:

- A user must have at least one row in `user_translation` table.
- I had to use `ANY_VALUE()` or `MAX()` to avoid this error: SQL Error (1055): Expression #20 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'trans.first_name' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by.
- The query takes ~0.250 sec. for only 16313 rows, imagine if there are 1,000,000 rows !
- The same query scenario is used for other tables like `countries`, `articles`, `news`, `groups`, `categories`.

---

#### Database Tables

##### Table: languages

```sql
CREATE TABLE `languages` (
    `id` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `lang_name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    `lang_code` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    `timestamp` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    `created_at` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `updated_at` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `languages_lang_code_index` (`lang_code`) USING BTREE
)
COLLATE='utf8_unicode_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

##### Table: users

```sql
CREATE TABLE `users` (
    `id` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `mobile` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    `email` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    `image` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    `gender` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
    `date_of_birth` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `timezone` VARCHAR(191) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    `score` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `is_searchable` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
    `is_deleted` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
    `role` TINYINT(4) NOT NULL,
    `status` TINYINT(4) NOT NULL,
    `uuid` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    `country_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `city_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `district_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `deleted_at` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `created_at` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `updated_at` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE,
    UNIQUE INDEX `users_uuid_unique` (`uuid`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `users_country_id_foreign` (`country_id`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `users_city_id_foreign` (`city_id`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `users_district_id_foreign` (`district_id`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `tmp_idx_deleted_at` (`deleted_at`) USING BTREE,
    CONSTRAINT `users_city_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`city_id`) REFERENCES `cities` (`id`) ON UPDATE RESTRICT ON DELETE SET NULL,
    CONSTRAINT `users_country_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`country_id`) REFERENCES `countries` (`id`) ON UPDATE RESTRICT ON DELETE SET NULL,
    CONSTRAINT `users_district_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`district_id`) REFERENCES `districts` (`id`) ON UPDATE RESTRICT ON DELETE SET NULL
)
COLLATE='utf8_unicode_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

##### Table: user_translations

```sql
CREATE TABLE `user_translations` (
    `id` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `first_name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    `second_name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    `third_name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    `last_name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    `user_id` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `language_id` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `created_at` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `updated_at` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `user_translations_user_id_index` (`user_id`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `user_translations_language_id_index` (`language_id`) USING BTREE
)
COLLATE='utf8_unicode_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

##### Table: countries

```sql
CREATE TABLE `countries` (
    `id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` VARCHAR(191) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_general_ci',
    `code` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_general_ci',
    `wiki_id` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_general_ci',
    `flag` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_general_ci',
    `is_deleted` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `timestamp` BIGINT(20) NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `created_at` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `updated_at` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `countries_code_index` (`code`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `countries_flag_index` (`flag`) USING BTREE
)
COLLATE='utf8mb4_unicode_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Comment: I am very ignorant to the level of fine tunning your query needs, but I had to work with worse queries, and one thing I found (thanks to another coworker that knew a lot about DBs) is that, instead of using multiple clauses in your `on`, try using one, the most important one, and any other clause just move it to the where, so move `AND \`trans\`.\`language_id\` = \`lng\`.\`id\`` out of `on` and put it on the `WHERE` clause and tell me if the timing changed for better

Comment: @matiaslauriti thanks, moving (AND `trans`.`language_id` = `lng`.`id`) out of `on` to the `WHERE` clause did not change the timing, actually rows count changed from 16,313 to 16,080, so the query is no longer accurate.

Comment: Please replace the images of the EXPLAIN output with text (ASCII or [markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#tables) tables). You should be using utf8mb4, not utf8(mb3). You do not appear to explicitly identify the _default_ translation. Is it simply the first row (based on created_at) per user. Why add the surrogate key for languages when you already have widely used language codes which have the benefit of being human readable? Assuming `user_id, language_id` should be unique within `user_translations`, you should either add the unique key or set it as the PK.

Comment: @user1191247 Thanks. I have replaced the images with Markdown. Do you mean i should change the `COLLATE` of the tables and columns from `utf8_unicode_ci` to `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` or `utf8mb4_general_ci`? The default translation is the first row inserted into `user_translations` table where `user_id` = user's id, so it can be based on `created_at` or even `id`. A user must have one translation at least and may have more translations (en, ar, fr, ..). The language code is received from the app.

Comment: [`utf8mb3`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.3/en/charset-unicode-utf8mb3.html) is deprecated and `utf8mb4` should be used for new applications. Which collation you choose is down to the needs and preferences of your application. What version of MySQL are you using (`SELECT VERSION();`)? Why not use the language code as the PK instead of the surrogate integer key? Are you able to provide a link to a dump of test data?

Comment: You get 76.3k records per second from this query's fastest run. There is a significant chance that the size of the result set is a bottleneck factor.

Comment: @user1191247 Version is "5.7.42-0ubuntu0.18.04.1-log". I thought `id` is the ideal PK since we have more than 10 tables with `language_id` foreign keys, but if making `lang_code` the PK will solve the query time significantly, i will do it. any chance `ANY_VALUE` is the culprit since it scans the whole table?

Comment: @O.Jones how so? what to do?

Comment: Using [`ANY_VALUE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.3/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_any-value) to return the _first_ of a group of values is not a valid approach. It may be that it does return the first value, but it should not be relied upon. It would probably be better to explicitly identify the default, either with a default flag on the `user_translations` or storing the default language in the `users` table. Then you remove the need for GROUP BY and can join explicitly to the data you are interested in.

Comment: Using the two character `lang_code` as the PK will make data easier to read without needing to constantly join to the `languages` table. Adding surrogate integer PKs does not make sense when a natural key exists, especially when it is widely used, user readable and short.

Comment: If your application must bulk-process tens of thousands of rows, there's not much weird SQL indexing voodoo magic that can speed it up beyond a certain point.  All those rows need to be pulled in from the database's storage, formattted for the MySQL network connection, pushed out over the network, read in by your application, and processed. That takes time.

Comment: No, I use `where` and `exists` a lot with these queries.